# Evaluate arrayfun only at nonzero entries different results

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am given two vectors x,y and i create the distance matrix

```
B=pdist2(x,y);
```

Now i evaluate a certain function f(x),

```
s=5;
if s-x > 0
    y=(1-x/s)^4*(1+4*x/s)/20;
else
    y=0;
end
```

where s is some paramter. By predefining s and using

```
A=arrayfun(@f,B);
```

the matrix A is positive definite as desired.

Since the matrix is sparse i want to evalute f(x) only at the values that will be returned nonzero. My attempt was

```
B=pdist2(x,y);
B(B>s)=0;
B=B/s;
indexB=find(B);
Atmp=arrayfun(@f,B(indexB));
A(indexB)=Atmp;
```

But now A is not positive definite and has less nonzero entries than before. Can someone explain what i am doing/is going worng?

Thanks everyone, i found the error. There where some zero entries on the diagonal in B which i had to calculate seperately.

Comment: Please write  the answer *as an answer* so others can see this question is resolved, or mark the most useful answer as accepted

Answer (score 4):

I'm wondering why you're trying to index `B`, and then apply some function to every individual element. Instead let's *vectorize* your code

```
% Same setup
B = pdist2(x,y); s = 5;
B(B >= s) = 0;  B = B/s;
% Don't use arrayfun, instead use vectorised code
% The previous line already dealt with the 'else' case from f(x) 
B = ((1-B/s).^4).*(1+4*B/s)/20;
```

Notice that every time we operate between two non-scalars, we must use *element-wise* operations `.^` or `.*`. The other divisions and multiplications are all with scalars, but we could be safe and get into the habit of using them all!

```
B = ((1-B./s).^4).*(1+4.*B./s)./20;
```

---

A note on MATLAB terminology: careful saying that you have a "sparse matrix" here, that is a [special variable type](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) in MATLAB. You have a standard matrix which is mathematically sparse! Operating on a sparse matrix could be slightly different.

Comment: Thank you for that note. But i have to apply more than just that one function on every element of the matrix. So using something like B = ((1-B./s).^4).*(1+4.*B./s)./20; would be tedious i guess.

Comment: Why would it be more tedious than applying it within some function `f(x)`? If you have to apply more than one function, you can apply them all at once? Please give an example of what you mean (as a question edit if it's something long / which needs formatting)

Answer (score 2):

You should preallocate the matrix `A` with the same size as `B`, otherwise MATLAB doesn't know the correct size for `A`:

```
A=zeros(size(B));
```

Note that [`find`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#buf0c2r-8) returns [linear indices](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511), so `A` became a vector instead of a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `arrayfun` you can use [spfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spfun.html) to apply a function to nonzero sparse matrix elements:

```
A = spfun(@f, B);
```

Though vectorization may be more efficient.

- spfun also works with dense matrices as well as sparse ones but output of it is a sparse matrix

Thanks to @Wolfie provided some testing and for their clarification.

Comment: As I noted below, the output `B` that they're getting from `pdist2` probably isn't a MATLAB sparse matrix... Not sure if that affects your answer.

Comment: @Wolfie Good point, However `spfun` works with dense matrices as well as sparse ones in Octave. I'm not sure for MATLAB...

Comment: Just done a minimal test in MATLAB (`s = [1 2; 3 4]; spfun(@exp,s);`) and it appears to work just fine, outputting a sparse matrix object (even if the input was a dense matrix). So this should be a decent solution, but the user should be aware of the output variable type